# Normalizing spanish dates in Java

Tags: java, date

I need to parse spanish dates with the following format (which are strings):

```
6 junio 2012 
20 mayo 2012
```

*junio* means june and *mayo* means may.

As you can see the month is written in spanish. How can I normalize it to get normalized dates (`yyyy-mm-dd`)?

In the example above I my desired output should be:

```
2012-06-06
2012-05-20
```

To be honest I dont know how to even start, searching a solution of this specific case is a bit hard.

Thanks in advance

Comment: its a date variable or string?

Comment: It is a string.

Comment: The marked as duplicated works with dates and I'm working with an input string.

Comment: @Avión: Indeed, but you can use the same `SimpleDateFormat` and use `parse(String)` instead of `format(Date)` , this will give you a correct date from a localized `String`.

Comment: Use java.time classes. `LocalDate.parse ( "6 junio 2012" , DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "d MMMM uuuu" , new Locale ( "es" , "ES" ) ) ).toString ()` → `2012-06-06`  (that is standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, BTW)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following code.  The trick here is to initialize the `SimpleDateFormat` with *both* a language and country, in this case Spanish (Español) and Spain (España).

```
String yourDate = "20 mayo 2012";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy", new Locale("es","ES"));
Date date = sdf.parse(yourDate);
System.out.println(date.toString());
```

**Output:**

```
Sun May 20 00:00:00 SGT 2012
```

If you want to format this Spanish date as `yyyy-mm-dd` you can again use the `format()` method from `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
System.out.println(sdf2.format(date));
```

**Update:**

The reason we use `MMM` in the format mask for the full month name is explained well in the [Javadoc for SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

> **Month:** If the number of pattern letters is 3 or more, the month is interpreted as text; otherwise, it is interpreted as a number.

I have seen both `MMM` and even `MMMM` being used to what seems to be the same effect.

Comment: Thanks. How can I parsed it to get the desired output format (`yyyy-mm-dd`)?

Comment: @Avión I have updated my answer per your requirements.

Comment: Use another SimpleDateFormat: SimpleDateFormat dateFormatOutput = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", localeOutput);       
     SimpleDateFormat dateFormatInput = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy", localeInput);
     
     date = dateFormatInput.parse(inputdate);     
     return dateFormatOutput.format(date);

Comment: Thanks a lot, Tim. Just a little question. Why there are three `M`s in the month part on the `new SimpleDateFormat` part? `"dd MMM yyyy"`? It should be just two?

Comment: FYI, the troublesome classes of `java.util.Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.